# Can we smooth a function on arbitrary small set with bounded $C^1$ norm?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Consider $f(x)=x $  if $x \ge0$ and $f=0$ if $x \le 0$

> For each $r \gt 0$ we can find a function $f_r $ such that $f_r = f$ when $|x| \ge 2r$ , $f_r \in C^{\infty} $ and $||f_r-f||_{H^1} \to 0$

We can choose $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}$ , $\phi=1$ when $|x|\le 1$ and $\phi=0$ when $|x|\ge 2$ , then $f_r := (1-\phi(\frac{x}{r})f(x)$ is what we want . And it can be shown that $||f-f_r||_{H^1} \to 0$ .

Since $f'(0-)=0,f'(0+）=1$ it seems that we can construct $f_r$ with $||f'_r||_{C^0}$ uniformly bounded , although $||f''_r||_{C^0}$ must tend to $\infty$ .

> For each $r \gt 0$ can we find a function $f_r $ such that $f_r = f$ when $|x| \ge 2r$ , $f_r \in C^{\infty} $ and $||f'_r||_{C^0}\le 2$    ?

Comment: Presumably you meant $\lVert f_r-f\rVert_{C^1(\mathbb{R}-\{0\})}$ not $\lVert f_r\rVert$.

Comment: @user10354138 Since $|f'(+-0)| \le 1$ ,  I want to find $f_r$ with $f'_r$ not so large . So this requires $||f_r||_{C^1} \le 2$  .

Comment: No, $f_r$ is bound to be large when $x$ is large, since $f_r(x)=f(x)=x$ for $x>2r$.

Comment: Sorry , it should be $||f'_r||_{C^0}$ , not $||f_r||_{C^1}$ .

Comment: Your $f_r$ has $f'_r(rx)=f'_1(x)$ so $f'_r$ is indeed uniformly bounded in $C^0(\mathbb{R})$.